# Mapping blob data in spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, gridfs

After reading of manual, it's easy to upload file in GridFS filesystem of MongoDB, but the thing which is missing there is what is proper method to map that file to particular entity?
Let's say we have User entity and user's avatar which is represented by GridFS file entry. how to map them properly?

Comment: Store a identifier from `User` to the image. The `id` could be whatever you want to make it.

Comment: that's what I'll do in case of nothing better will be on the table.

Comment: That's how MongoDB works -- unless you have some other way to reference the GridFS file you've stored. http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-save-image-example/